# Automatic Reference Counting - Message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

I made a class that acts as the delegate of several other classes. There's a problem though. **ARC is prematurely releasing this class** and when a delegate message is sent to it, the program crashes. I don't understand why... I set the class to strong. How can  ensure that this class is not released?

ViewController.h

```
Class *__strong class;
```

---

ViewController.m

```
class = [[Class alloc] init...];
```

---

Class.m

```
-(id)init {

    self = [super init];

    Object *object = [[Object alloc] init...];
    object.delegate = self;

    return self;

}
```

---

Log

```
-[Object respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x11453f40
```

Comment: `object` instance of `Object` is released before `return self` under ARC as it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Local variables are deallocated when the function exits, no matter how many memory qualifiers you may decide to append to them.

Answer (score 1):

You've got your answer, but I figured I'd chime in with a little tip of my own. I always remove my classes from the notification center at dealloc.

```
-(void) dealloc{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

This might be overkill for some, but I lean on the notification pattern quite heavily to achieve as lose couplings as possible. With the asynchronous nature of notifications combined with ARC this is almost a necessity.